# How to fix overlaping items in grid layout in NativeScript?

Tags: html, angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am creating a mobile quiz-type game using NativeScript and Angular.  I want to generate a 3 x 8 grid from given array that is 24 items long.

I tried using the code with rows and columns set like shown below, also I tried set all to "*" and "auto".

```html
<ActionBar title="Riddle #1" icon="" class="action-bar">
</ActionBar>
<StackLayout>
    <Image src="res://some_image"></Image>
    <GridLayout rows="auto, *, auto" columns="auto, *, *, *, *, *, * auto">
            <Label *ngFor="let character of riddleCharacters; let i = index" row="i/8" col="i%8" [text]="character"></Label>
    </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Unfortunately, all the items get placed in position 0,0 and they overlap each other.I would like them to form a 3 x 8 grid.
I gladly appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: You are not binded to the index property when setting row and col

Comment: `[row]="i/8" [col]="i%8"`

Comment: Btw I think that it would be easier to use WrapLayout or FlexBoxLayout instaed of dynamically assigning the Grid rows and columns

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much, after adding the binding it works great!
I will stick to this one (because it is already working after all), but I will test later Wrap or Flexbox for this case :)